# Making a half circle path with CGPath, and follow the path with SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, cgpath

I have no idea how to make a half circle path with CGPath. There is the code i have:

```
  let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
  let Width: CGFloat = 38.0
  let radius: CGFloat = (Width / 2.0) + (Treshold / 2.0)
  CGPathAddArc(pathOne, nil, x, 0.0, radius, firstPoint.position.x, secondPoint.position.x, true)
  let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
  let moveAction = SKAction.followPath(pathOne, duration: 3.0)
  capOne.runAction(SKAction.sequence([waitAction, moveAction]))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        let square = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
        square.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        addChild(square)

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(0, 0), radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), clockwise: false)

        let pathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.CGPath)
        pathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        pathNode.lineWidth = 3
        pathNode.position = square.position
        addChild(pathNode)

        square.runAction(SKAction.followPath(bezierPath.CGPath, asOffset: true, orientToPath: true, duration: 2))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, hamobi. That's what I looking for)

Comment: How can I calculate the startAngle and endAngle from two sprites positions,  if i want to swap both of these sprites with half circle path. I tried your example, but your half circle not fixes my problem. I need half circle path above of two sprites, when i swap first sprite with second, and another half circle below them, when i move second sprite to first ones.

Comment: I've post another question could you look at this please)